# Where is the '+' method is defined in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

`+` is a method.

```
5 + 3 #=> 8
5.+(3) #=> 8
```

Can anyone show me the method definition of `+`?

Comment: Which one? There are seven different definitions of `+` just in the core library, many more in the standard library, and countless more in third-party libraries and gems. Also, which implementation are you talking about? Rubinius, YARV, MRuby, JRuby, IronRuby, MagLev, Opal, Topaz, … all have different implementations of the core library.

Comment: If you're looking for integers, [here it is](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/98fa0ab4d955cf275ceb15573a5d40edd2e82522/numeric.c#L3544-L3562). Probably isn't very useful. Can you ask specifically what you want to know so we can be more helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the source of `Integer#+` for 2.5.0:

```
      VALUE
rb_int_plus(VALUE x, VALUE y)
{
    if (FIXNUM_P(x)) {
        return fix_plus(x, y);
    }
    else if (RB_TYPE_P(x, T_BIGNUM)) {
        return rb_big_plus(x, y);
    }
    return rb_num_coerce_bin(x, y, '+');
}
```

It's usually easy to find it in documentation:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-2B

Keep in mind what Jörg W Mittag pointed out - there are number of `+` methods and for example method `+` defined on what's returned by `4.4` literal will differ, because it's `Float`, not `Integer`.

You also may have noticed that it's C, not Ruby. It's because Ruby interpreter, MRI, is written in C, so no wonder that the core functions of this language (like `Integer` class and its methods) are also written in C.

Answer (score 2):

Just for your information, there is a gem that provides documentation/source code for Ruby in shell : [pry-doc](https://github.com/pry/pry-doc)

It is a plug-in for [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) (another ruby shell)

It's very useful and helped me every day. I really recommend it for any ruby project.

Your case is pretty particular and gave me a headache trying to get the `+` method source. I learned that when looking for operator (`+`, `-`, `==`, `<<`, ...) source code or documentation, you have to put a `.` in front the operator.

Example

```
pry(main)> ? [].==

From: array.c (C Method):
Owner: Array
Visibility: public
Signature: ==(arg1)
Number of lines: 7

Equality --- Two arrays are equal if they contain the same number of elements and if each element is equal to (according to Object#==) the corresponding element in other_ary.

   [ "a", "c" ]    == [ "a", "c", 7 ]     #=> false
```

Below is how to use it in your case

```
[1] pry(main)> x = 5
=> 5
[2] pry(main)> show-source x.+

From: numeric.c (C Method):
Owner: Integer
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 11

VALUE
rb_int_plus(VALUE x, VALUE y)
{
    if (FIXNUM_P(x)) {
  return fix_plus(x, y);
    }
    else if (RB_TYPE_P(x, T_BIGNUM)) {
  return rb_big_plus(x, y);
    }
    return rb_num_coerce_bin(x, y, '+');
}


[3] pry(main)> x = 5.0
=> 5.0
[4] pry(main)> $ x.+

From: numeric.c (C Method):
Owner: Float
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 16

static VALUE
flo_plus(VALUE x, VALUE y)
{
    if (RB_TYPE_P(y, T_FIXNUM)) {
  return DBL2NUM(RFLOAT_VALUE(x) + (double)FIX2LONG(y));
    }
    else if (RB_TYPE_P(y, T_BIGNUM)) {
  return DBL2NUM(RFLOAT_VALUE(x) + rb_big2dbl(y));
    }
    else if (RB_TYPE_P(y, T_FLOAT)) {
  return DBL2NUM(RFLOAT_VALUE(x) + RFLOAT_VALUE(y));
    }
    else {
  return rb_num_coerce_bin(x, y, '+');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the implementation in Opal](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/number.rb#L42-L51):

> ```
> def +(other)
>   %x{
>     if (other.$$is_number) {
>       return self + other;
>     }
>     else {
>       return #{__coerced__ :+, other};
>     }
>   }
> end
> ```

You may have noticed that it is Ruby with embedded ECMAScript which in turn has Ruby embedded in it. Opal is a compiler for the ECMAScript platform, so some low-level methods are partially implemented in ECMAScript for performance reasons.